# FileNoFoundException при открытии файла в assets

Tags: java, android, android-assets

Пробую читать текстовый файл с assets и выдаеться ошибка: FileNoFoundException.

```
am =getApplication(). getAssets();
public void readFile(View v){
    try
    {
        InputStream is = am.open("test.txt");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        String text = new String(buffer);
        tv1.setText(text);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.d("Tag", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        tv1.setText("file not found");
    }

}
```

Список файлов могу получить таким способом из asset, а открыть нет. Файл с таким именем в списке есть.

Comment: И?... в чем заключается Ваш вопрос?.. как таки открыть файл из assets? или как обработать Exception?

Comment: Как открыть файл.

Comment: Добавьте скриншот из Android Studio, где видно содержимое assets.

Answer (score 0):

Чтение текстового файла.

```
private String getFile(String fileName) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
        try {
            InputStream file = assetManager.open(fileName);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file, "Windows-1251"));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                buf.append(str);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }
```

Comment: У меня все равно выдает эту же ошибку!

Comment: Проверьте регистр имени файла и того, которого пытаетесь открыть. в Android это имеет значение.

Comment: Регистр тот же. Список файлов в assets могу получить.Файл в списке присутствует. Когда пытаюсь открыть выскакивает ошибка.

Comment: Clean/Rebuild Project делали?

Comment: Это логи в logCat?